# Google Play Games without Google Plus

Tags: google-account, google-play-games

Lots of Android games have some "achievement" features that give you badges for completing some task in the game. This sounds like fun and I'd like to try it.

Apparently, those features are only available once you are signed in to Google Play Games. I don't mind that. I do mind, however, that trying to register to Google Play Games asks me to create a Google+ profile, which I definitely do not want (I don't want another social networking account, and I particularly don't want a potentially public social networking account associated with my personal gaming activities).

Is there are way to use Google Play Games features without a Google+ account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It **is possible** now. As mentioned [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2016/01/play-games-permissions-are-changing-in.html)

- Players are prompted to sign-in once per account, rather than once per game
- Players no longer need their account upgraded to Google+ to use Play Games services
- Once players have signed-in for the first time, they will no longer need to sign in to any future games; they will be automatically signed in

Note: Players can turn off auto-sign-in through the Play Games App’s settings

Answer (score 4):

No, it is not possible to use Google Play Games without a Google+ account because much of Google Play Games is social and so it makes sense for it to integrate it with Google+. But if you don't want to use the social side of Google+ but still use Google Play Games, you could create a Google+ account and disable all the social features, make every aspect of your profile private and also disable all social options in Google Play Games too.