# Google Play Games still seems to require a Google+ account?

Tags: google-play-games

I try to login to Google Play Games (version 3.6.27), but it  still asks me for a Google Plus account. According to this answer: [Google Play Games without Google Plus](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/136733/156357), no Google+ account should be required anymore.

Why is it asking for that account then? What further info now should I be knowing about the new gamer ID login, instead of a Google+ login?

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG:]

Comment: Quick question: are you currently logged in one of your Google (not G+) accounts?

Comment: Yes I am logged into my Google account for GMail, but I do not have a Google+ account for that Google account.

Comment: From a theoretical point of view, I think that the Play Games app demands you to have a G+ account, in order for Google to perform its "anonymous" data aggregations and analytics. Still, I've no proof.